# Chain RethinkDB filtering with document manipulation

Tags: node.js, rethinkdb

I am trying the following with RethinkDB (NodeJS driver):

```js
const cursor = await r.table('users')
  .filter({ 'username': friendRequest.initiator })
  .getField(friends)
  .append(friendRequest.target)
  .run(conn)
```

But I get the error stating `Expected type DATUM but found SEQUENCE`.

How do I first filter and then manipulate documents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
r.table('users')
  .filter({ 'username': friendRequest.initiator })
```

returns array, but `getField` only works for objects.

As I can see, you want to filter users and get filed "friends" and append new record to it. You should use [`pluck`](https://rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/pluck/) for this and after use [`map`](https://rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/map/) on the result:

```
const cursor = await r.table('users')
  .filter({ 'username': friendRequest.initiator })
  .pluck(friends)
  .map(function(row){
     return row(friends).append(friendRequest.target);
  })      
  .run(conn)
```